# EF 3.1 LINQ Expression could not be translated virtual entity contains

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to filter some records using the following code:

```
return base.CreateFilteredQuery(input)
            .WhereIf(input.OrganisationUnitId > 0, t => t.Records.Any(x => input.OrganisationUnitId == x.Record.OrganisationUnitId))
            .WhereIf(!input.Term.IsNullOrEmpty(), w => w.CreatorUser.FullName.Contains(input.Term));
```

But I'm getting the 'classic' recent error of:

```
.LeftJoin(
    outer: DbSet<User>
        .Where(u => __ef_filter__p_8 || !(((ISoftDelete)u).IsDeleted) && __ef_filter__p_9 || ((IMayHaveTenant)u).TenantId == __ef_filter__CurrentTenantId_10), 
    inner: p => EF.Property<Nullable<long>>(p, "CreatorUserId"), 
    outerKeySelector: u => EF.Property<Nullable<long>>(u, "Id"), 
    innerKeySelector: (o, i) => new TransparentIdentifier<PrintJob, User>(
        Outer = o, 
        Inner = i
    ))
.Where(p => p.Inner.FullName.Contains(__input_Term_1))' could not be translated.
```

I know w.Status.Contains(input.Term) works no problem so I assume its the CreatorUser child entity that it does not like. How am I meant to run a query on any child entities?

Comment: It's not a recent error, it's there since 2008. The query can't be translated to SQL so EF complains about it. EF Core 1.0 was so incomplete that even a simple `GroupBy` couldn't be translated, so it just loaded partial results in the client so it could filter or group the rest of the data on the client. Needless to say, this leads to horrendous performance, unsuitable for production-level applications

Comment: In the code you posted though it's impossible to say what the query is. There's no `CreateFilteredQuery` or `WhereIf` in EF Core or LINQ. There's no `IsDeleted` property. What is the *actual* query? Where did the left join come from?

Comment: Have you tried to implement [global query filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters) for tenants and soft-deletes?